# Differential equation for leaking bucket.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

A bucket with cross sectional area $A$, with a hole of area $a$ is filled with water.

by conservation of mass

$$A\frac{dh}{dt}=-a\frac{dx}{dt}$$

I don't understand where the minus is coming from, if anything shouldn't the minus sign be on the left hand side? as the height of the water is decreasing? Could someone elaborate

Comment: Do you mean like this $-A\frac{dh}{dt}=a\frac{dx}{dt}$? BTW what is $x$?

Comment: No, that's how I would write it though. It's from lecture notes, I suppose multiplying though by -1 doesn't harm. He has not defined $x$, well, he said that $Adh$ becomes $adx $ in some time $t$.

Comment: what is $h$ and what is $x$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The volume change is equal to the volume of water that runs in minus the volume of water that runs out.

Nothing comes in, so the volume change $Adh=0-adx$ where $dx$ is the height of a small water cylinder that escaped the bucket under the time $dt$. Equivalently
$$
A\frac{dh}{dt}=-a\frac{dx}{dt}=-au
$$
where $u(t)=dx/dt$ is the water velocity at time $t$. After that I guess Bernoulli's law or Torricelli's law will come to play.

Comment: Yes, the next line gives $mgh = \frac{1}{2}mv^2$, I am struggling to interpret that in this context? I know this is another issue.

Comment: $mgh=$ potential energy, $\frac12 mv^2=$ kinetic energy. Think why are they equal.

Comment: When a unit of water is at height $h$ in the bucket its total energy is potential, when the water exists the bucket it is purely kinetic?

Comment: You can look [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Torricelli%27s_law)